# why is list().append() giving me duplicated values?

Tags: python, list

When i pass a list of strings into this function i want it to return a matrix saying how many times each unique word appears in the string, but, i get a matrix with the values for the first string repeated 4 times.
This is the code

```
def tf(corp):
words_set = set()
for i in corp:
    a=i.split(' ')
    for j in a:
        words_set.add(j)
words_dict = {i:0 for i in words_set}
wcount=0
matr=list()
for doc in corp:
    for worduni in words_dict:
        count=0

        for words in doc.split(' '):
            if words==worduni:

                count+=1
        words_dict[worduni]=count/len(doc.split(' '))
    print(words_dict)
    matr.append(words_dict)   

return matr
```

when i print the value of matr, i get
[{'the': 0.2,
  'first': 0.2,
  'document': 0.2,
  'third': 0.0,
  'is': 0.2,
  'one': 0.0,
  'and': 0.0,
  'this': 0.2,
  'second': 0.0},
 {'the': 0.2,
  'first': 0.2,
  'document': 0.2,
  'third': 0.0,
  'is': 0.2,
  'one': 0.0,
  'and': 0.0,
  'this': 0.2,
  'second': 0.0},
 {'the': 0.2,
  'first': 0.2,
  'document': 0.2,
  'third': 0.0,
  'is': 0.2,
  'one': 0.0,
  'and': 0.0,
  'this': 0.2,
  'second': 0.0},
 {'the': 0.2,
  'first': 0.2,
  'document': 0.2,
  'third': 0.0,
  'is': 0.2,
  'one': 0.0,
  'and': 0.0,
  'this': 0.2,
  'second': 0.0}]

Comment: What’s the input to that function, `corp`? Aside from that, there is a lot of refactoring to be done. This code is really all over the place.

Comment: And why are you calling your output a matrix? It’s a list of dictionaries. If you looked carefully, you would see that **all** the words are duplicated, because what you have is a list of four dictionaries, since you append `words_dict` at the end of every loop iteration.

Comment: You only have one `word_dict` and you append it multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your code is doing is repeatedly adding the same object (`word_dict`) to `matr`.  Naturally, since `matr` is a list it can handle this ... and you will have multiple references to the same dictionary.  Meanwhile, you are updating the dictionary.  So what you see when you print the list is the final state of the dictionary ... N times.

Now I suspect that you intended to save *snapshots* of the state of `word_dict` in `matr`.  But if that's want to do, you need to save *copies* of `word_dict` in `matr`; e.g

```
    matr.append(words_dict.copy())
```

On the other hand, if your intend to generate a separate word frequency dictionary for each `doc` in `corp`, then you need to move the creation and initialization of `word_dict` inside the outer loop.

---

Separately to the above, the way you are counting the words and computing the frequency seems to be completely wrong.  I am assuming that is what you are *trying* to do here.

---

Note: if you use more meaningful method and variable names and/or add appropriate comments to your code, it will be easier for other people to understand what your code is *intended* to do.

Comment: adding the copy() worked. I can see that the code is horrible (i am only starting to code), other than that i seem to be to getting the required output. I should have specified this in the question but, what i want is to get the count of each unique word in the list of strings corpus in each string in corpus, i cant think of how to phrase that better. Thanks.

Comment: So what you need to do is accumulate the word counts in the dict.  Something like this:  `counts[word] = counts[word] + 1`.  And reinitialize the counts for each document.

Answer (score 0):

I modified this to get you non duplicated data that is identical to your print:

```
def tf(corp):
  words_set = set()
  for i in corp:
      a=i.split(' ')
      for j in a:
          words_set.add(j)
  words_dict = {i:0 for i in words_set}
  wcount=0
  matr=list()
  for doc in corp:
    for worduni in words_dict:
       count=0

       for words in doc.split(' '):
          if words==worduni:
             count+=1
       words_dict[worduni]=count/len(doc.split(' '))
    print(words_dict)
    matr.append(words_dict.copy())   

  return matr
```